# Update PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, upgrade, php56, dotdeb

I wonder if anybody has **successfully updated PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6** yet on **Debian squeeze** and would kindly share how this can be done. My server's current system is running since 7+ years.

> Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)
>   PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch
>   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Already was reading [updating Debian to higher versions](https://serverfault.com/questions/404815/how-can-i-upgrade-php-to-a-higher-version-for-debian-squeeze). Something about using *wheezy* or *dotdeb.org* sources and pinning. Further is it needed to update Apache http server too for PHP 5.6?

The reason I need to update is a problem with PHP CURL that's best described here: [TLS 1.2 not working in cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145089/tls-1-2-not-working-in-curl). I'm running php-cli scripts through crontab that connect to https sites and more and more fail lately. On a Windows System I already verified that with PHP 5.6 all works fine.

As I understood, the only solution would be an update to PHP 5.6. I'd also appreciate if there is any other solution like only upgrading the [package php5-curl](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/php5-curl). Also I don't know how this would be done. Maybe the TLS problem can be solved in a different way, I couldn't find one.

So the last stable and supported PHP version for *sqeeze* seems to be the one I'm running. After `apt-get update` there is nothing new (lot's of 404 sources not found errors).

Comment: Squeeze is out of support for 2.5 years. Don't upgrade single components of it, instead upgrade to a [supported Debian version](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). You need Jessie as the minimum, and preferably Stretch.

Comment: You're far past the point where you can continue to run squeeze. You should have upgraded to a current Debian distribution years ago. You put it off far too long and now you have no other options.

Comment: Because somebody said *never change a running system*. And it's running since about 2010 now (where I did the last upgrade) even without a restart. Isn't that amazing. And now I'm scared when I do a dist upgrade, I'll kill the server and there is running lots of stuff on it.

Comment: Build a new server off to the side on current versions. Actually, build two - you need a test box. Restore data to it and get things running. Cut over when validated. No updates in 7 years is neglect. The minimum you must do is security updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sven's comment needs to be an answer: [Squeeze is end of life since 2016-02-29.](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze) You should get to a [version with security or LTS updates](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS), currently Stretch or maybe Jessie.

I do not have a problem with using frozen versions of old software with suitable security controls. But the need to get later versions of components shows the need to maintain this thing.

Eventually you just won't find suitable packages for this distro, even from third party repositories.

Comment: Finally I did the [dist upgrade over Wheezy to Jessie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41028053/5527985). It was a lot of work. Bunch of config files to update/rewrite, scripts to adjust and boot problems, but finally after ~36 hours everything is working fine. Was worth the effort :)